# How to find an identity of the last inserted row in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am inserting data in multiple tables. I need to know the last inserted (auto-incremented) ID in the table. I need to use it as a Foriegn Key in some other table.

In short I need alternative of `@@Identity` in T-Sql.

Comment: It is **recommended** to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Entity Framework will automatically load the last inserted id to populate the primary key column of the inserted entity:

```
var customer = new Customer { Name = "Steven" };

context.AddObject(customer);

context.SaveChanges();

var id = customer.Id;
```

Note that the `Id` property only gets populated after calling `SaveChanges()` in case the `StoreGeneratedPattern` attribute is set to "Identity" or "Computed" for the auto-incremented ID column in the Storage part of the model.

Comment: This is correct only in case the StoreGeneratedPattern attribute is set to "Identity" or "Computed" for the auto-incremented ID column in the Storage part of the model.

Comment: Where and how do you set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` attribute to "Identity" or "Computed"

Answer (score -2):

Anyhow if you need the the id for some any other purpose ... calling EF Insert Method for some  entity automatically returns the currently inserted row id ...

```
var rowId=db.Insert(Entity);
```

Comment: There is no `Insert` method and EF's `Add` method does *not* return the identity value. This answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -3):

You could also use this code to see the last column of your data base.

```
var lastColumn = context.YourTable.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Doesn't give any guarantee that the returned value is from your own insertion. There may be concurrent users. The accepted answer is the only correct answer until today, albeit that the syntax has changed.