# Add single entry to ICollection dynamically one at a time (MVC4 EF)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, persist, icollection

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this issue: Is there a way to add a single entry to an ICollection? One at a time, persisting the data to the database for each entry added?

**Here is my specific situation:**

I have a Test Model:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

A Test contains a Collection of Questions. Question Model:

```
public partial class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }

    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is for a user to have the ability to create a test, with a name and description, and then dynamically add questions to that test until they are satisfied. As of right now, creating the test is easy, but loading the test with questions is proving challenging for me. I had envisioned a form that would submit a Question and a Test.Id to a controller action which would persist the data to the database. But I don't understand how I can dynamically add a question to a ICollection of a Test.

Is there a way to add a single entry to an ICollection? One at a time?

One of the many attempts I've made

Thank you so much for any help!

**In response to levelnis:** I tried this with no luck

```
    public void AddQuestionToTest(Test test, Question question)
    {
        question.Test = test;
        test.Questions.Add(question);
        Update(test);
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

It's not adding any questions to the db. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The only code I've tried that gets a question into the database is:

```
public void AddQuestionToTest(Test test, Question question)
{
    question.Test = test;
    Insert(question);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

..but this makes another Test in the database with the same name/description but a new id that has been incremented.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but would this not work?

```
test.Questions.Add(new Question{ Id = 1, query = "set your question up here" });
```

You would then need to update and save changes on the test via EF to persist it back to the database.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. Added to question to show what I tried.

Comment: Do you need to insert the question first and then add it to the test and update?

Comment: If I Insert(question). The question gets persisted to the database but it duplicates another test with an ID that incremented by one. The test has same name and description though.

Comment: Make sure the question is only added to a test after it's been inserted and saved

Comment: I've tried. I added a bit more to my question. Thank you so much for trying to help, I really appreciate it. Been at it for 10 hours today.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like such a simple overlook, but here is what I was doing incorrectly:

I was creating a new test in the database with a test Object. I was then attempting to use that same object to set Question.Test. This was causing a new test to get created when I inserted the question to the data base.

After inserting a new test into the database, I had to query the database to find that test, and assign that test to Question.Test.

It seems strange because it is identical to the test I persisted, but I guess there is something going on behind the scenes which I am unaware of.

Thank you to levelins for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds like you're not getting the id of the `test` after saving it. Is the `Id` a primary key as far as EF is concerned? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068084/how-to-find-an-identity-of-the-last-inserted-row-in-entity-framework - `Insert()` returns the id of the entity that was inserted and your `test` needs its `id` property set, otherwise EF will think it's a new entity and try and insert it again